# Can one prevent Chrome causing an infinite loop when displaying alerts on the focus event, without disabling and re-enabling the event?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom-events

Consider the following code.  If I click in `cmbMonkeys`, it causes an infinite loop of alert messages in Google Chrome.  My workaround for `cmbPeople` works fine.  Does anyone know of a another way to prevent infinite loops when displaying alerts on focus or blur events, without disabling and re-enabling the event?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var eventHandler;

        function cmbPeople_OnFocusHandler() {
            alert("focus");
        }

        function cmbPeople_CallFocusHandler(control) {
            eventHandler = control.onfocus;
            control.onfocus = null;
            cmbPeople_OnFocusHandler();
        }

        function cmbPeople_CallBlurHandler(control) {
            control.onfocus = eventHandler;
        }

        function cmbMonkeys_FocusHandler(control) {
            alert("I like monkeys");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    monkeys <select id="cmbMonkeys" onfocus="cmbMonkeys_FocusHandler(this)"></select>
    people <select id="cmbPeople" onfocus="cmbPeople_CallFocusHandler(this)" onblur="cmbPeople_CallBlurHandler(this)"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a simple state-handler, maybe?

```
var isFocus = false;
function cmbPeople_CallFocusHandler(control) {
    if(!focus){
        focus = true;
        cmbPeople_OnFocusHandler();
    }
}

function cmbPeople_CallBlurHandler(){
    isFocus = false;
}
```