# Chrome onblur with alert dialog causes eternal annoyance. How do I break out of this loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert, infinite-loop

A module for an ecom we work with uses a javascript `alert()` box to fire off a warning when certain input contents are invalid. When combined with `onblur` in html it causes eternal popups in Chrome in certain cases. To replicate a case, visit this fiddle in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/a4rsbf6e/1/.

Now, click the input box. You should see a cursor blinking in there (in `onfocus` state). Then click basically anywhere that isn't in the current tab or address bar. This inits the `onblur` event. You should see `alert()` spamming over and over locked in a loop because of the "out of scope/viewport" click. The console also thinks it's a long task violation. The only thing I can see to do here is close the tab....which stinks if it's something like a big quote/form/product because it erases the filled in datas. Less savvy users like Grandma may not understand what is going on, especially when they try to close/minimize the browser or switch tabs.

I have reported the bug to Chrome and the dev, but in the meantime, is there any way to break out of this loop when it happens? I have seen some other topics regarding `onblur`, is there a way to easily "overrule" the event in the case it starts going haywire?

I realize I can make a different type of message method, but I don't want to re-write someone else's module [further] because of a browser bug. I have already spent too much time bug fixing with this module and don't really want to start refactoring the validation to boot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one prevent Chrome causing an infinite loop when displaying alerts on the focus event, without disabling and re-enabling the event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151027/can-one-prevent-chrome-causing-an-infinite-loop-when-displaying-alerts-on-the-fo)

Comment: @JohnWu Hmm I see how it's similar. I can try to overrule the `onblur` somehow in a global way, although I have never tried that. Reading more about touchy `onblur`, the dev should have used some other event/method to trigger the validate function IMO.