# Chrome: Blur - Alert - Focus sequence causes infinite alert loop

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, alert

Consider this code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("hello");
input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  alert('hello');
  input.select();
  input.focus();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="hello" id="hello" />
```

The idea around it is to keep the user focused in the input until he/she enters a valid text in it. This is a simplified version of the code.

Js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wzwft49w/9/

**Problem:** If you focus on the input and then blur it, you will get an infinite alert popup in Chrome but not in IE.

*1. How would you solve this problem?*

*2. Any ideas on why does this happen?*

Notes:

- I already checked this question but that fix doesn't work in this case: [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151027/can-one-prevent-chrome-causing-an-infinite-loop-when-displaying-alerts-on-the-fo)
- Here's an old Chrome bug related to blur and focus (not sure if it could have anything to do with this, although it is marked as solved): [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117307)

Comment: wrap the `input.select(); input.focus();` in a setTimeout (o milliseconds is fine) - this will fix firefox also. in firefox case, the input is not focussed after the alert

Comment: Use something other than `alert` to display the message. Ideally something that doesn't need to be clicked on to dismiss.

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried that before and it works most of the time. The problem is that if the user has the input focused and then opens a new tab, the infinite loop will happen again.

Comment: @4castle unfortunately that's not an option in this case.

Comment: Why would that not be an option? I can't imagine that an obnoxious input box with an alert is a good idea.

Comment: @4castle legacy code that has this all around the app, so the fix would involve a huge amount of effort. More like customer constraints

Comment: @ashish gupta I ended up adding flags in the code to control when the alert should be shown. To solve the alert loop when minimizing the browser or changing tabs I ended up using the Visibility API supported natively on all current browsers: document.hidden (with this flag I also decided if I should show the alert or not)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for chrome:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input"), 
    len = inputs.length, 
    i;
    var gflag=false;

    function myalert(m,o) {
        if (gflag) {
            return;
        }

        gflag=true;
        alert(m);
        o.focus();
        setTimeout(function() {gflag=false;},10);
    }
    
function makeBlurHandler() {
    "use strict";
    return function () {
      if (this.value === "") {
          myalert("Cannot be blank!",this);
          this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Cannot be blank!";
      } else {
          this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "";
      }
    };
}

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("blur", makeBlurHandler());
}
```

```css
.errorMessage {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="userName">User Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="userName">
  <span class="errorMessage"></span>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="passWord">Password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="passWord">
  <span class="errorMessage"></span> 
</p>
```

it work for IE too, but this not for Firefox due to focus() is not working correctly.